# Are any of these scalars equal to 0?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $T : V \longrightarrow V$ be a linear transfromation.

Suppose $ r_1,  r_2,  ...,  r_m$ are distinct eigenvalues of $T$ and
$v_1, v_2, ..., v_m$ are corresponding eigenvectors. Then $v_1, v_2, ..., v_m$ is linearly independent. My question is if any of these scalars $r_1, r_2, ..., r_m$ could be equal to $0$? II think that yes, but not plenty sure.

Comment: yes; for example, if $V$ is any non-zero vector space, the linear transformation $T:V\to V$ given by $v\mapsto 0$ for all $v\in V$ has $0$ as its *only* eigenvalue. if this example feels too trivial, let $(b_i)_{i}$ be any basis for $V$, and define a map $T:V\to V$ by extending $b_0\mapsto 0$ and $b_i\mapsto b_i$ for all $i\neq 0$. then $b_0$ is an eigenvector of $T$ with eigenvalue $0$. in general, $0$ will be an eigenvalue of $T$ if and only if $T$ is not injective

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose they are linearly dependent, without loss of generality $v_1 = a_2v_2+\dots a_nv_n$.

Let $p(x) = \prod\limits_{i=2}^n (x-r_i)$

then $p(T)(r_1) = p(r_1)v_1 \neq 0$, but on the other hand $p(T)(v_1)= \sum\limits_{i=2}^n p(r_i)v_i = 0$, a contradiction.

Comment: I was trying a way to get it, Thanks a lot.

Comment: Glad to be able to help.